# How to make a function act as a generator only when used as one

Tags: python, python-asyncio, generator

One existing example of this is `open` which can be used in these two ways:

```py
f = open("File")
print(f.readline())
f.close()

# ...and...

with open("File") as f:
  print(f.readline())
```

I intend to create a version of the asyncio.Lock class which allows you to not only acquire and release the lock manually but also to use a `with` block to wrap the code that requires the lock and release it automatically.

Comment: Not seeing the generator here. Can you be more explicit about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think Rillian confuses context managers with generators

Comment: @Mark Create a function that can be used on its own and after the `with` keywork

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan That seems to be the case. So should I just impliment `_enter_` and `_exit_` on the Lock object and run `with` on the object itself? `lock = Lock()` `with lock:`

Comment: `asyncio.Lock` can be used with `async with`, see the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you look for isn't a generator, but a context manager.

You don't even need to implement one, This works:

```
lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def example():
    async with lock:
        # Your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

For other people getting here: although the OP wanted something that already works out of the box:

Whenever one sees a "function" that can work as a generator or a context manager, as is the case, or be used "stand alone", it is due to the fact it is not a "function": it is actually a *class* . WHat you do when calling `open` or `asyncio.lock` is creating an object, which internally has several methods, not only `.read` or `.acquire`, which both have to be explicly called, but special named methods which allows Python to call then in a transparent way, when the object is used in certain language constructs.

For example, if the class implements the `__iter__` method, it can automatically be used in `for` statements. To be used with an `with` statement, it has to implement both `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.